# What kind of "link" is Saint referring to?

Tags: dialogue, charlies-angels

In *Charlie Angels* (2019), in the closet room, Saint gearing Elean up:

> Bosley: Tattoos are earned by Angels over time. You'll get a less
>   permanent version.
>
> Saint: Yeah, comms are concealed in **the link**.

[Source](http://transcripts.thedealr.net/script.php/charlies-angels-2019-L7ZW)

What kind of "link" is Saint referring to?

Comment: Having read the entire context, a) I'm sure it must be 'ink' & b) the entire segment is just a lot of pseudo-tech arm-waving; the equivalent of *"compensating the phase shift of the dilithium crystals' multisubsonic warp fusion with the rubindium subspace containment field."* for a generation who own mobile phones & ear-buds.

Comment: @Tetsujin that's target audience for the movie.. P.S: welcome back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's about communication link a.k.a comm.link. consider the conversation before you mentioned, from same [page](http://transcripts.thedealr.net/script.php/charlies-angels-2019-L7ZW)

> Shall we fit Elena with comms?
>
> I think so.
>
> Oh, that in-ear radio thing you guys have?
>
> Ah, even better.
>
> It's a subdermal transmitter.
>
> Works through bone conduction. See?

It says about a Sub-dermal transmitter, Sub-dermal transmitters are embedded into the skin, hidden from outside.

> A subdermal implant refers to a body modification that is placed
>   underneath the skin, therefore allowing the body to heal over the
>   implant and creating a raised design. Such implants fall under the
>   broad category of body modification. Many subdermal implants are made
>   out of silicone, either carved or mold injected.

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdermal_implant) says.

**P.S:** I'm not sure that transcription mentioned is correct, but since you insist on it, consider this as different POV answer.

Comment: Re: my comment above - why would a subdermal transmitter work through bone conduction? The microphone might, but the transmitter… hnh??  ;)) [/me waves arms indicatively…]

Comment: Usually, I just go meh and push 'em to movie logics bin and discard further thoughts on that. but in this instant could it be the power source for transmitter? I dunno

Comment: Except the movie explicitly says she isn't getting a subdermal one, so the majority of this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: @BCdotWEB OP didn't ask whether she actually gets one, just about what some phrase meant. they were talking about it. explaining what is, how is etc.. Anyway, if this one is irrelevant, perhaps you can come up with a better *relevant* answer?

Comment: @Vishwa But the phrase doesn't point to the subdermal transmitter. See https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/107105/13595 .

Answer (score 1):

I think you misheard "ink" for "link" as in their communication equipment is hidden in the tattoos.

According to the transcript you use as a source it even says: "It's a subdermal transmitter."meaning it is placed beneath the skin which means that covering it up with a tattoo makes perfect sense.

Comment: What makes you think a user transcript is more likely to be correct? Though we probably can't prove it one way or the other until it's out on DVD/Netflix etc with official subs, ink makes far more sense than link.

Comment: @FredMcShane in the context Link doesn't make any sense at all while Ink makes perfect sense and is actually a clever way of doing things.

Comment: Nope, they clearly say "link". Likely refers to (a part of) the bracelet she is given while he's saying this.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - that might have been rather useful information to have had in the original question. Not something anyone is going to guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

He's referring to the bracelet he's putting on her:

[image: screenshot with subtitles]

Why he calls it a "link" is unclear to me, though perhaps he's referring to the knot-like part of the bracelet, considering that the bracelet looks like it consists of two interlinked pieces.